# Run a ruby / gem repo on mac

Tags: node.js, ruby, rubygems

I'm a node.js dev, I want to run this app https://github.com/seven1m/bible_parser

Installed ruby and gem, but what's next?

Comment: Gem is a library, so you need to actually write some code in Ruby using it. An example is in the repository. This should go to some file, say `bible.rb`, which is then run with `ruby bible.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to interact with the gem is probably by using IRB (this is the standard Ruby REPL, and is analogous to using the `Node` command in your terminal to open the Node REPL).

In your terminal (I'm assuming you're working on a Unix-like OS), run the following command:

`$ irb` - if you've installed Ruby correctly this should open an IRB session

Once inside IRB, you can run Ruby commands and have them immediately evaluated and executed. From here you can run the usage example from the gem's README:

```
require 'bible_parser'

bible = BibleParser.new(File.open('web.usfx.xml'))
verse = bible.books.first.chapters.first.verses.first
# => <Genesis 1:1>
verse.text
# => "In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.\n"
```

Of course, this presupposes that you have a valid XML document available.